# is there any method to count the number of ways in which 100 can be expressed as sum of even integers?

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, integer-partitions

can anyone help me out with this problem, which is as follows; my friends gave me the challenge to count the no. of ways in which 100 can be expressed as the sum of even positive integers.
I spent hours and got an answer, and I am a bit unsure that the answer is approximately 589826.
can anyone help me out, please?
I am actually searching for an answer, and I am trying to ask that how many ways are there to write 100 as the sum of positive even integers.

Comment: You are basically asking the number of ways $50$ can be partitioned, for that there is no simple technique.

Comment: This is actually a [Stars and Bars](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) question with the following three *wrinkles* to consider: [1] The problem is equivalent to finding $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots x_k = 50.$ [2] For a given $k$, the problem is equivalent to finding the number of non-negative solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = (50-k)$.  [3] With $n$ fixed at $(50)$, and $n$ adjusted to $(50 - k)$, you actually have $(50)$ different Stars and Bars problems, since $k$ can be any element in $\{1,2,\cdots, 50\}.$

Comment: I therefore moderately disagree with the comment of @Ritam_Dasgupta.  That is, since, for each $k \in \{1,2,\cdots,50\},$ an **appropriate** binomial expression of the form $\binom{a}{b}$ exists, the overall computation has the closed form of the sum of $(50)$ binomial expressions.

Comment: No, in your method, the groups are distinct, whereas in a partition they are not. For example $49+1$ should be the same as $1+49$, but that's not what you are doing.

Comment: Wait actually yeah, it depends. Do you consider 2+4 the same as 4+2? Or are these considered different???

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta Very good point.  This implies that it comes down to interpretation of the OP's intent, as to whether $1 + 49$ is distinct from $49 + 1$.  I definitely agree that if the OP's intent is as you claim, rather than as I claim, then my Stars and Bars approach becomes problematic.

Comment: @user2661923 I have edited my answer now to include both possibilities

Comment: To the OP: for what it's worth, keeping in mind that $k \in \{1,2,\cdots,50\}$, then regardless of whose interpretation you *intend*, you can **sanity** check your computation via software, using something like C or Java.  I recommend your doing that, to determine whether you have made an analytical mistake.

Comment: @user2661923 agreed, the problem is incomplete.

Comment: If $2+4$ is different from $4+2$, then you have a string of $50$ sausages with $49$ places you may or may not chop, to leave $2^{49}$ possibilities.

Comment: If order matters, you're low by a factor of about $10^9$.  If order does not matter, you're high by about a factor of 2.  The relevant mathematical terms are, respectively, integer compositions and partitions.

Comment: if order doesn't matter, I have no opinion on the right enumeration.  If order does matter, I can confirm the comment of @BrianHopkins, as follows:  For any $k \in \{1,2,\cdots, 50\}$, the number of non-zero solutions to $x_1 + \cdots x_k = (50-k)$ is $$\binom{[50-k] + [k-1]}{[k-1]} = \binom{49}{k-1}.$$  Therefore, the enumeration is  $$\sum_{k=1}^{50}\binom{49}{k-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{49}\binom{49}{k} = 2^{(49)}.$$  Then, since $\log_{10} (2) \approx (0.301)$, $$2^{(49)} \approx 10^{(14.749)} \approx 5.6 \times 10^{(14)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: actually, on second thought, the answer depends. Do you consider, for example, ${2+4}$ the same as ${4+2}$? If you do, then you can follow what @user2661923 said in the comments. Otherwise, you must do the following: note as stated by @Ritam_Dasgupta, your problem will be in one-to-one correspondence to finding partitions of ${50}$. Given a partition of ${50}$,
$$
50 = k_1 + ... + k_n
$$
then you get
$$
100 = 2k_1 + ... + 2k_n
$$
i.e. you get ${100}$ as the sum of even positive integers. Likewise for
$$
100 = 2c_1 + ... + 2c_n
$$
then dividing both sides by $2$ gives a partition of ${50}$. It's easy to see with a little thought these will be in one-to-one correspondence.

Solving partitions is a highly non-trivial problem, you can approximate the answer  by using:
$$
p(n)\sim \frac{1}{4n\sqrt{3}}\exp\left(\pi \sqrt{\frac{2n}{3}}\right)
$$
plugging in ${50}$ will give you a number much larger than yours stated.

Comment: Minor typo in your editing.  If the OP considers $2 + 4$ as **different** than $4 + 2$, then my approach is appropriate.